# Deleting shapefiles and rasters using arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, workspace, error-999998

I am trying to delete a series of files from a gdb and I am encountering suprising difficulties doing so. When I test my procedure in one of the files, let's call it 'yy.shp'This is what I do:

```
from arcpy import env 
from arcpy.sa import * 
import os 
env.workspace  = env.scratchWorkspace = "path/to/my/GEODB.gdb"
arcpy.Delete_management(r'yy.shp')
```

And I receive the error:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 1, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3995, in
>   Delete     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error

Notice that if I do:

```
arcpy.Exists(r'yy.shp')
```

I get a `TRUE` result

What am I doing wrong? I have checked and there is definitely no mistake in the path or names of the files. I got these names by dragging and dropping the gdb and file into the python console.

Comment: You **can't** delete a shapefile from a file geodatabase because you can't put a shapefile *in* a file geodatabase in the first place.  They are different formats, and not interchangeable. It is not legal to create a FGDB table with a period in the table name.  If you have used the operating system to corrupt the `.gdb` directory contents with a shapefile set of files, you'll need to remove them from the directory (using the OS) before you can generate a legal name for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297459/deleting-shapefiles-and-rasters-using-arcpy/297469#comment478274_297459):

> You **can't** delete a shapefile from a file geodatabase because you
>   can't put a shapefile *in* a file geodatabase in the first place. 
>   They are different formats, and not interchangeable. It is not legal
>   to create a FGDB table with a period in the table name.  If you have
>   used the operating system to corrupt the `.gdb` directory contents
>   with a shapefile set of files, you'll need to remove them from the
>   directory (using the OS) before you can generate a legal name for
>   deletion.